# SQL Conditional INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, sql-insert

I'm using MySQL.  How can I execute an INSERT into a table predicated upon validation of related data?  Forgive the contrived example.

If my tables are:

```
> SELECT * FROM colors;
id color  owner
-- ------ -----
10 red    2
11 banana 6
12 blue   9
```

and

```
> SELECT * FROM fruit;
id  color_id  name
--  --------  -------
59  10        cherry
60  12        blueberry
```

Where fruit.color is a foreign key to colors.id

I want to insert info about a banana, but only if the owner of the color is 6.  Here's the raw INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO
    fruit
    (color_id, name)
VALUES
    (11, 'banana');
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO
    fruit
    (color_id, name)
VALUES
    (11, 'banana')

-- ??? I have no idea what to put here ???
ONLY IF (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit
    INNER JOIN colors ON fruit.color_id = colors.id
    AND   colors.id     = 11
    WHERE colors.owners = 6) >= 1
)
```

That last clause is obviously not real, but I don't know what to do there.  The idea is only INSERT the values if the `owner` column of the `color_id` I'm trying to insert is equal to the value I provide.

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
insert into fruit (color_id, name)
select 11, 'banana'
where (select count(*) from fruit join colors on fruit.color_id = colors.id
where colors.id = 11 and colors.owner = 6) >= 1;
```

or equivalently

```
insert into fruit (color_id, name)
select 11, 'banana'
where exists 
(select * from fruit join colors on fruit.color_id = colors.id
where colors.id = 11 and colors.owner = 6);
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  I wan't aware that INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... could be used that way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit
    INNER JOIN colors ON fruit.color_id = colors.id
    AND   colors.id     = 11
    WHERE colors.owners = 6) >= 1
THEN
   INSERT INTO fruit
   (color_id, name)
   VALUES
   (11, 'banana');
END IF;
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work; I kept getting syntax errors.